# Reshape 1D numpy array to 3D with x,y,z ordering

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, reshape

Say I have a 1D array of values corresponding to x, y, and z values like this:

```
x  y  z  arr_1D
0  0  0  0
1  0  0  1
0  1  0  2
1  1  0  3
0  2  0  4
1  2  0  5
0  0  1  6
...
0  2  3  22
1  2  3  23
```

I want to get `arr_1D` into a 3D array `arr_3D` with shape `(nx,ny,nz)` (in this case `(2,3,4)`). I'd like to the values to be referenceable using `arr_3D[x_index, y_index, z_index]`, so that, for example, `arr_3D[1,2,0]=5`. Using `numpy.reshape(arr_1D, (2,3,4))` gives me a 3D matrix of the right dimensions, but not ordered the way I want. I know I can use the following code, but I'm wondering if there's a way to avoid the clunky nested for loops.

```
arr_1d = np.arange(24)
nx = 2
ny = 3
nz = 4
arr_3d = np.empty((nx,ny,nz))
count = 0
for k in range(nz):
    for j in range(ny):
        for i in range(nx):
            arr_3d[i,j,k] = arr_1d[count]
            count += 1

print arr_3d[1,2,0]

output: 5
```

What would be the most pythonic and/or fast way to do this? I'll typically want to do this for arrays of length on the order of 100,000.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You where really close, but since you want the x axis to be the one that is iterated trhough the fastest, you need to use something like

```
arr_3d = arr_1d.reshape((4,3,2)).transpose()
```

So you create an array with the right order of elements but the dimensions in the wrong order and then you correct the order of the dimensions.

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks! I tried some other transpose thing that didn't work, not sure why I didn't try that one.